# How to run python apps using Procefile on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I've deployed my app on Heroku and run dyno. By default it searches for main.py module and runs it, but I want to specify the folder and app to run. How can I do this?

[This is how it's normally works by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPRUt.png)

[But I want to run app from the "app" folder as it illustrated in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyubW.png)

Comment: `By default it searches for main.py module and runs it`. Doubtful. Can you share your Procfile?

Comment: it's almost empty, has just default one line worker: python main.py $PORT

Comment: There is no default. It always depends on the project. It is also there where you define how to run your application.

Comment: I found the answer

Answer (score 0):

in Procfile we can include our processes and name them as it show in code below

```
proc_name: python folder_name/app_name.py
```

And run it on Heroku CLI
`heroku ps:scale proc_name=1`